# Find values of the parameter m for absolute value equation to have two positive solutions

Tags: absolute-value

I solved an equation with absolute value and parameter and I got two different results when I applied two methods for this question. Could you please help me to spot and explain what am I doing wrong?

Question: Find values of the parameter $m$, for which the equation $\quad x−|4−2x|=2m \quad $ has 2 positive solutions.

My first attempt was based on the definition of the absolute value:

$$|x| =
\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
-x, & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$

so, I got:

$$|4-2x| =
\begin{cases}
2x-4, & \text{if } x \geq 2, \\
4-2x, & \text{if } x < 2.
\end{cases}
$$

Then, in the calculated domains, I found the x value. I had:

$$1^\circ \quad x + 4 - 2x = 2m \implies x =  4-2m \quad\text{if}\quad x \geq 2$$
$$2^\circ \quad x - 4 + 2x = 2m \implies x =  \frac{4+2m}{3} \quad\text{if}\quad x < 2$$

Next, I thought that if I want to have two positive solutions, both $x$ should be a positive in their domains, so I got

$$1^\circ \quad 4-2m > 0 \implies \quad x  \in \emptyset \quad\text{if}\quad x \geq 2$$
$$2^\circ \quad \frac{4+2m}{3} > 0 \implies \quad  x \in (-2, 2) \quad\text{if}\quad x < 2$$

When I take a common part of these two solutions, I finish this task with no $m$ for which this equation has two positive solutions.

However, when I try to solve this graphically, I define $m = \frac12 (x - |4-2x|)$ and sketch the right hand side of this equation

Graph of the function $\quad m = \frac12 (x - |4-2x|)$

[image: Graph of the function <span class=]$\quad m = \frac12 (x - |4-2x|)$" />

It is clearly visible that two positive solutions are for $m \in (-2, 1)$. Could you please help me in finding the mistake in my consideration? I really want to solve this question without a graphical method.

Comment: You got $4-2m>0$ so how does that show $x\ge 2$ is not possible?

Comment: You're right, thank you. I messed up with domains, I took a common part for these solutions, but I forgot one inequality is for $m$, but restrictions are for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a final step you need to solve that :

$$
\begin{cases}4-2m≥2\\
 0<\dfrac {4+2m}{3}<2\end{cases}
$$

which yieds $m\in(-2,1)$ .

Comment: Could you please explain more why you calculate these values as greater than 2 or less than 2? And why do you restrict the second case by 0 as well?

Comment: @Dracks Sure. Because, we need $\color{red}{x}=4-2m≥2$ and $\color{red}{x}=\frac{4+2m}{3}<2$ and $\color{red}{x}>0$ which yields the above system of inequalities. However $x≥2$ implies that $x>0$ is redundant. But, there is no issue here .

Answer (score 1):

- If $x=2$ you have $x=2m$, so $m=\frac x2 \in \{ 1\}$
- If $x >2$ you have  $x=4-2m$,  so $m= \frac{4-x}2 \in (-\infty, 1)$
- If $0<x < 2$ you have $x=\frac {4+2m}{3}$, so $m=\frac{3x-4}2 \in (-2,1)$

You want two positive solutions for a given $m$, and the only non-empty intersection here is between $(-\infty, 1)$  and $(-2,1)$, and is  $(-2,1)$.

This shows any $m\in (-2,1)$ will give two positive $x$s, one above $2$ and the other in $(0,2)$, and no other $m$ will do.